# Deploying program with sol_remaining_compute_units() gives "invalid account data"

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, program, deploy, account-data

Including something like
msg!("remaining compute: {}", solana_program::compute_units::sol_remaining_compute_units());

will lead to error when deploying

> RPC URL: https://api.devnet.solana.com Default Signer Path:
> /root/.config/solana/id.json Commitment: confirmed
> ========================================================================= Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
> `solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
> ========================================================================= dial rain team erupt super bread apart guitar obvious dutch nothing
> cheap
> ========================================================================= To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the [BUFFER_SIGNER]
> to `solana program deploy` or `solana program write-buffer'. Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the [BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to` solana program close`.
> ========================================================================= Error: Deploying program failed: RPC response error -32002:
> Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid
> account data for instruction [3 log messages]

Comment: Please add your full code, else we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Which build tool or command are you using to build your program?

What version of the Solana tool suite you are using to deploy?

Try updating all the tools to the newest version and try again.